# Cannot Add Comment to Late Answer

Tags: bug, review-queues, comments

I am trying to add a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5451578# saying something to the extent of "please summarize the contents of the link as part of your answer". Unfortunately I cannot add a comment (whenever I try I get get brought back up to the top of the review page). My only option is to go back to the main review page and hope that someone else can/will do I wanted to do. Unfortunately others seem to be having this issue as well as the answer keeps on appearing on the queue after every few answers I review.

Now it appears that this was a review audit (I had this suspicion, but I was not sure).

Happened again for me with this question (I assume also a review audit as the answer is not present for the actual question): https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5463387

And this question https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5463403#

Also down-voting the questions works and brings me to the review passed page.

Comment: When I was still participating in reviews I would always click the link to the actual page, so I could see what was going on with the question in general.

Comment: This has just happened to me for http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5590490# I am using latest version of Chrome. My best guess is - Initially it was genuine review, but post got deleted while I reviewed - so got converted to audit ... bug or feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work).

If you visit [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863867/android-google-mapview-suggestion), you'll see that the answer is no longer visible: it was flagged or automatically placed in a review queue and was selected for deletion.

The system did not allow you to comment because you cannot comment on deleted/locked posts.

However, the `add a comment` action should have triggered a pass on a negative post audit instead of jumping to the top of the page, so you might have resources blocked or JavaScript disabled.

Comment: See the update. I am now aware this was a review audit. However I do believe clicking `add a comment` should have triggered an audit pass hence why I think this is a bug.

Comment: Happened again. The strange thing is that review audits were working fine for me before and I haven't changed any JavaScript settings. I also tried clearing the cache, but without success.