# Can't comment on a deleted answer in the Late answer review queue

Tags: bug, review-audits

I know this is possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267597/cannot-add-comment-to-late-answer) (or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268751/cant-click-on-add-a-comment-in-first-post-review-audit) as gnat pointed out), but the behavior is happening again, and what the accepted answer says (that clicking on "comment" should make you pass the review) just doesn't work.

This is for [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6064908#)

I understand what happens. The answer is deleted, and therefore I can't comment on it. But clicking "add comment" just doesn't do anything. When it happens I realize that it is a deleted answer and I downvote/flag, but maybe the system should make it a pass when you comment? According to the answer on that other question, it is exactly what it's supposed to do (make you pass the audit), but it doesn't.

Comment: As an aside, it's a bit odd that the answer was apparently deleted as "not an answer".  It's not a *good* answer (it's probably incorrect, as it looks like it would report the status of the service vs. whether a tunnel is actually active) but it certainly does appear to be an attempt at answering.

Comment: related: [Can't click on “add a comment” in First Post Review audit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268751/cant-click-on-add-a-comment-in-first-post-review-audit) _'What is supposed to happen when we click on "add a comment" on an audit?'_

Comment: Hey @gnat... I saw that, I actually linked it as well, but thx.  As I pointed out, the answer says "it should let you pass the audit", and it doesn't yet.

Comment: I saw your link, but it was to a [different question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267597/cannot-add-comment-to-late-answer), that's why I commented. Look at the "Linked" section to the right - there are two questions there now

Comment: @Gnat my bad... I must've clicked on yours and then I went to a tab which had my link. Didn't realize my mistake. :)

Comment: looking at that